# Basic Shade problem in Eevee (light strip shows where it shouldn't) version 2.9x

Tags: eevee-render-engine, light, lighting

I have another shade problem in Eevee which I couldn't find a solution or reference: when I put some vertical plane on a horizontal one (or extend the horizontal to add a vertical one) and light them, there is always a line of light between the vertical and horizontal and sometimes it is very wide even if you make sure that the vertical touches (or exceeds down) the horizontal plane.

[image]

Comment: ok i could reproduce your issue here. It happens if the wall is too thin. If you make it thicker, it won't happen. But i have no idea why it happens.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you.. you can see that my planes are not really "too thin".. 
I don't seem to find how to include a file here..  (another question :) )

Comment: I agree with you. I have no idea...And i am curious what the Pro's will explain us ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using *Eevee* (maybe clarify this in the question). There are two ways which you most likely have to combine to get "contact shadows".

1. Go to the *Object Data Properties* of the light source which is shining on the object and enable *Contact Shadows*. Maybe this still doesn't look correct, try changing the *Distance* value for example and experiment with the values generally.

[image: contact shadows light source]

2. In the *Render Properties* you'll find settings for *Shadows*, mostly for the quality and resolution so changing the values might result in slower performance. If you increase the *Cascade Size* from its default 1024 px to 4096 px it will make the shadow look better, but on each end of the wall you can still notice there's no real contact shadow.

[image: shadow properties]

In the end it's maybe best to combine both settings to get the best looking result with the least performance loss.

Comment: and learnt again something with lighting ;)  +1

Comment: @Chris What distracts me most in finding a solution is that most people do not care to specify the render engine anymore, and while almost everybody seems to use Eevee nowadays I sometimes don't realize the issue when I recreate it, because I'm almost exclusively working with Cycles.

Comment: Some also don‘t waste a second to think about how they could help us so that we can easily help them. I just wonder how some people want a whole simulation solution with step by step tutorial without providing anything at all…I use eevee too nearly 95% because I am impatient….

Comment: Thanks a lot @Go it worked fine. 
I found also that increasing "Thickness" woud help in a similar way, but must not be exagurated. There was no perfect solution for all cases and angels, and there is always something wrong somewhere on some angle, but for my purpose it was great, thanks again

Comment: @SaiebKhalil Yeah, as I said experimenting with the settings might get you some result you're confident with. The problem I had with _Thickness_ was that when I increased it on the left end of the wall it looked like the shadow was even extending to the backside of the wall - where the plane is in full sunlight, which definitely didn't look correct.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, Yes that's exactly what I noticed. That's why I wrote "there is always something wrong somewhere on some angle". I think it is an issue for the developers

Comment: @SaiebKhalil I'd say it's mostly because Eevee is not a Raytracer, so shadows are always somewhat "fake" and an approximation. If you want realistic shadows you should use Cycles.