# Why is my Eevee light shining through my mesh and how do I fix it?

Tags: rendering, mesh, eevee-render-engine, lighting

**Introduction:**

I am making a house in Blender 2.93.5, and so far it has over 1,500 objects and about 130 lights in all. It has multiple rooms, each with a separate set of lights each, and one large hall to connect them. I was about to install lights in the hall when a problem turned up.

**The problem:**

When I went into rendered mode to see the hall without lights, I found it fairly bright with lights from behind the walls.

[image]

**What I have attempted:**

I have attempted many things to get the walls to block the light and the light to not shine through the walls, including adding solidify modifiers and things like that, but nothing worked. *I have also combed through all related Blender stackexchange questions and answers,* but none of them did any good at all and my problem still remains.

**Other info:**

Cycles does not have this effect, but with all those lights it takes way too long to render anything, and as I hope to use this house for a video game I am developing, that would be extremely inconvenient. Basically, I'd like an answer for Eevee. I don't want to just switch to using Cycles.

Comment: Maybe my answer here helps: [Basic Shade problem in Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229675/basic-shade-problem-in-eevee-light-strip-shows-where-it-shouldnt-version-2-9x/229686#229686)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann No, very similar but slightly different problem. I tried it, but it didn't work. Like most of the errors I get, this one seems to be evasive of solution . Thank you for the effort, anyway.

Comment: If the lighting is from an HDRI, there is no way to remove it's "indoor influence" without removing it's lighting influence from the scene entirely. If the lighting is from scene lights (point light, spot light, etc...), make sure to enable _Contact Shadows_ Under the light's _Object Data Properties_ under the _Shadow_ menu (you will need to click the small arrow to expand the options to see it). You will need to do this for each light source.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett That is almost exactly what Gordan Brinkmann's answer said, and even still I tried it and it didn't work. These lights *are* from scene lights, but no matter what I do to the lights' properties they still shine through the walls. Is there something in mesh properties I need to change?

Comment: Try giving the mesh some thickness (solidify modifier perhaps). If that doesn't work or is not an option, go for basic "debugging" - disable all the lights and see if the problem persists, if it's dark, then enable the lights one by one until you start to see a problem, then focus on that light, and what's special about it that might be causing it to "bleed" through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Answer** (*finally*)**:**

I found the answer to my problem at last while exercising the manifest help from @ChristopherBennet. In doing so, I found one overlooked option in the inferior  lights' settings: Radius. I am currently in the process of changing the wall-mounted lights' sizes to a smaller radius so that they do not extrude past the wall they are positioned on. I was surprised that the answer was so obvious and that I had not noticed it even after a day and a half of trying to figure it out. I give almost all credit to @ChristopherBennet that my hall is now blacker than tar .

Happy Blending!