# How to switch to EVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am trying to prevent/reduce an added 'light' from passing through a mesh object and found some Youtube tutorials all of which seem to use EEVEE rendering and wondered how you switch between CYCLES and EEVEE as I could not find the answer here or in the Blender Manual.
The reason I ask is that the video tutorials show using EXPONENT parameter listed 'under' SHADOW which I do not see and so think that I must be using CYCLES (where do I look to see what renderer I am using?).
Or if the video tutorials have used a different version of Blender where can I find the (Shadows) EXPONENT parameter?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the small window section below the outliner. Open the render tab (the second button that looks like a camera). See picture below for reference. Under *Render Engine* select whichever you would like. Eevee is a real-time renderer. Cycles takes more time and is more consuming of GPU/CPU but the result is more realistic. [image]

Comment: Thanks heaps. Well it seems that EEVEE must be the default as when I open my model it is already selected. I wonder then where I might find the EXPONENT parameter ('under' SHADOW) in version 2.92 (the video tutorials uses version 2.8)? The tutoriall I mentioned can be viewed at   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvTK16w7Ffs

Comment: I have now found that that Blender versions since 2.8 do not have the EXPONENT parameter for SHADOW. What a pity as it would have solved my problem.

Comment: There's a section on shadows in EEVEE in the Blender manual here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/eevee/render_settings/shadows.html and one on light settings here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/eevee/lighting.html.

Comment: Thanks John, I will have to try and work out if anything there will fix the 'problem I have.  What I am trying to achieve is to prevent light passing through a mesh. I saw a video tutorial which explains exactly that where the author placed a light INSIDE a model of a house and the OUTSIDE walls of the house were slightly lit (due to light coming through the walls) and he used the EXPONENT to reduce that to either NO light or very little. EXPONENT doesn't exist any more (parameter of Shadow) and I am trying to find out if there is an other way of replicating what EXPONENT did.

Answer (score 0):

After a trial and error 'experiment' it seems that setting BIAS to 0 might be what I need.     I placed a light inside a mesh cube with a very large 'power' and noted light shining from inside the cube onto the mesh plane under it. When I set BIAS to 0 there was no light coming from the cube onto the plane.

Comment: Here in this answer I give some examples of how the shadow settings in Eevee affect the result, in addition to what you figured out yourself: [Basic Shade problem in Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229675/basic-shade-problem-in-eevee-light-strip-shows-where-it-shouldnt-version-2-9x/229686#229686)

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I had seen how light leakage around the mesh could be reduced using Object Data Properties of the light source but hadn't seen anything about changing render properties. There are so many places where Shadow parameters can be modified. Do all these affect the output of the model ie the changes you see in Blender will be seen in the model outputted (I create models for use in MSFS2020)?

Comment: All settings how to generate or render shadows in Blender are - like all other material settings as well - dependent on the render engine, like Eevee or Cycles. Since MSFS2020 doesn't render in Eevee or Cycles I don't they are relevant there. OF course it also depends on which export format you are using and how much of the settings can somehow be transferred to that format. But a general rule is: only Blender works with Blender-specific materials and settings, like other software alike.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon.  "Since MSFS2020 doesn't render in Eevee or Cycles I don't they are relevant there" - I have done a heap of testing in the last 2 days that seems to be correct as applying BIAS seems to have no affect in MSFS - the light still comes through an object instead of appearing as a shadow. Very annoying for me as I have applied 'lights' on my bridge model and no matter what I do the water UNDER the bridge continues to be illuminated (from the lights above the bridge deck) which is annoying. deck. Maybe Asobo might fix that in the future.

Comment: That's no wonder. Usually each and every 3D software and gaming engine have their own materials and render engine. There might be similarities, but even if something is called exactly the same in two different softwares, the way it is realized in terms of coding might be very different and often incompatible. So I guess this is not even a Blender question, since the light leakage bothers you in MSFS2020 and I suspect none of the Blender shadow settings will be implemented in MSFS2020 in any way.