# Eevee sunlight leaking through entire building object

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm working with Eevee for the first time and I'm running into an unexpected artifact: Light from the sun object is passing through an entire building object and casting a shadow on the underside of the object. Is there a fix?

Visible in the attached example is a shadow of the arches appearing on the bottom of the building.

I've researched this and have learned that Eevee light leaks are a known issue, but none of the solutions I've tried thus far have had any effect. Compounding the issue is that this is an animation where the camera travels around the building. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.3.0, Windows 11

[image: example]

Comment: My workaround is to turn off the sun entirely, and since the scene is already lit by a procedural HDRi, the sun isn't missed. I'm so used to Cycles that Eevee is throwing me some curves.

Comment: Try messing with the bias settings in the light properties, and also make sure you have contact shadows enabled.

Comment: Maybe my explanations on contact shadows in _Eevee_ here: [Basic Shade problem in Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229675/basic-shade-problem-in-eevee-light-strip-shows-where-it-shouldnt-version-2-9x/229686#229686) might help you figuring out how to get rid of this.